# Multiple xampp version on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, webserver, xampp

How can i have 2 versions of xampp server running on my ubuntu 14.04 system. I searched for help https://gist.github.com/laborautonomo/3c39edfa8961c69b27cd. Could not get the expected result. Got stuck in symlink. Any more fruitful approach?